# Reserve a range of values in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to reserve a range of values for the system like [1-10,000]. The user values should be inserted after 10,000. eg. There is a table that will have values inserted by the system & will also have values inserted by the user. So, when a system inserts, the id's assigned to it will have to be between 1 to 10,000. If the user inserts a value, the values can be anything greater than 10,000.

Comment: You can put the seed of the identity column to 10000 and use Identity Insert for you "system" values . But why would you want to do this? Isn't it a better design to have a table for your system values, and a table for user values?

Comment: 'reserve a range of values" - what values, please add more details so we know context like is this this the primary key column, more than one column value, the identity column, some other we cannot guess detail regarding?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I want to reserve integer values. I already specified it in the question.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear, please put the code you have tried and the table layout in the question.  Otherwise it is a simple "Yes" answer to " Can I handle this thing in sql"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating identity column in SQL Server and setting the seed starting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362800/updating-identity-column-in-sql-server-and-setting-the-seed-starting-value)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss No.

Comment: Please edit and add more details to your question, as it stands there are too many unknowns to give a proper answer.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss. I have updated the question. Can you give your feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [check constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#Check) to ensure the condition has been satisfied:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [Col01] INT
   ,CONSTRAINT [CH_StackOverflow] CHECK ([Col01] < 1 OR [Col01] > 10000)
);


INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([Col01])
VALUES (-1);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([Col01])
VALUES (1);
```

If the column must be populated automatically, you can use [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) column like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [Col01] INT IDENTITY(10001, 1)
   ,[Col02] NVARCHAR(12)
);


INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([Col02])
VALUES ('x');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([Col02])
VALUES ('y');

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
```

Lately, you can use [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to add your special records.

If you need more control, you can use [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - instead of/after INSERT and UPDATE. You can add more logic there - reject the user input or transform the user input. But it feels like an overkill and you need to be careful when creating triggers - always process rows in batches to ensure you are not affecting to much your CRUD performance.